# Sorting dates in AngularJS frontend

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I have a table rendered with a few records and their creation date. The `$scope` data looks like this:

```js
$scope.data = [{
  "FeeId": "17",
  "FirmName": "LAWFIRM1",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Fixed",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "13-DEC-16"
},{
  "FeeId": "18",
  "FirmName": "LAWFIRM2",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Open",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "11-DEC-16"
}]
```

I need a AngularJS frontend based sorting on the by `startDate`. It's currently not working with a date in `string` format.

How can I sort my data by `startDate` in frontend using AngularJS?

Comment: Finaly feedback, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your date format `13-DEC-16` is custom to the common [ISO-Dates](http://momentjs.com/docs/) its hard to parse that date. In that way I changed your format from `13-DEC-16`  to `13-12-16`. I'll hope you are able to change your API data structure. Just a hint, it would be a nice improvement if you are using a ISO-Date format inside your API. So other system / languages would be able to handle that date too.

I would preffer a solution using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) which provides nice helpers by using dates in JavaScript. You need to parse the date to ensure correct date sorting in AngularJS. Until that you can use [AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) `orderBy` to sort by date in your frontend:

```
filter:orderBy(array, expression[, reverse]);
```

Your view would look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data|orderBy:'startDate'">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Your controller would be look like this:

```
//init scope data
$scope.data = [
    {
        "FeeId": "17",
        "FirmName": "LAWFIRM1",
        "countryId": "IN",
        "filing": "REI-Reissue",
        "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
        "feeType": "GOVT",
        "Term": "Fixed",
        "Amount": "150",
        "comments": "test comment",
        "startDate": "13-12-16"
    },{
        "FeeId": "18",
        "FirmName": "LAWFIRM12",
        "countryId": "IN",
        "filing": "REI-Reissue",
        "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
        "feeType": "GOVT",
        "Term": "Fixed",
        "Amount": "150",
        "comments": "test comment",
        "startDate": "14-12-16"
    },{
        "FeeId": "19",
        "FirmName": "LAWFIRM12",
        "countryId": "IN",
        "filing": "REI-Reissue",
        "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
        "feeType": "GOVT",
        "Term": "Fixed",
        "Amount": "150",
        "comments": "test comment",
        "startDate": "11-12-16"
    }
];

/**
 * Parse custom date format with moment js
 */
angular.forEach($scope.data, function (item, key) {
    $scope.data[key].startDate = new moment(item.startDate, "DD-MM-YY")._d;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
$scope.jsonObj = [{
  "FeeId": "1",
  "FirmName": "ABC",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Fixed",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "13-DEC-16"
},
{
  "FeeId": "2",
  "FirmName": "XYZ",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Fixed",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "13-NOV-16"
}];

for(var i in $scope.jsonObj) {
  $scope.jsonObj[i].startDate = Date.parse($scope.jsonObj[i].startDate);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in jsonObj | orderBy:'startDate'">{{item.FirmName}}: {{item.startDate | date}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a conversion object along with `substr` and `parseInt` to compare part of the date string however you please:

```js
//Month conversion object
var months = {
  NOV: 11,
  DEC: 12
};
//Sort function
function sortByDate(a, b) {
    return (
      //Year
      parseInt(a.startDate.substr(7, 2)) - parseInt(b.startDate.substr(7, 2)) ||
      //Month
      months[a.startDate.substr(3, 3)] - months[b.startDate.substr(3, 3)] ||
      //Day
      parseInt(a.startDate.substr(0, 2)) - parseInt(b.startDate.substr(0, 2)));
  }
  //The list to sort
var list = [{
  "FeeId": "17",
  "FirmName": "LAWFIRM1",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Fixed",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "13-DEC-16"
}, {
  "FeeId": "17",
  "FirmName": "LAWFIRM1",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Fixed",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "13-NOV-16"
}, {
  "FeeId": "17",
  "FirmName": "LAWFIRM1",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Fixed",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "13-DEC-15"
}, {
  "FeeId": "17",
  "FirmName": "LAWFIRM1",
  "countryId": "IN",
  "filing": "REI-Reissue",
  "agentFeeCode": "AGNT",
  "feeType": "GOVT",
  "Term": "Fixed",
  "Amount": "150",
  "comments": "test comment",
  "startDate": "13-NOV-16"
}];
//Sorting the list
console.log(list
  .sort(sortByDate));
```